# Error on Camera application on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, camera

**Hi**

I created a custom camera app with `SurfaceView` and when running the app, it just freezes the whole phone and shows black screen. When running on AVD, gives this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()' on a null object reference

*It's referencing the line where* `parameters = camera.getParameters();` *is called*

Here's the code:

**CameraActivity.java**

```
   public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    android.hardware.Camera camera;

    @InjectView(R.id.s)
    SurfaceView surfaceView;

    @InjectView(R.id.takeaphoto)
    ImageView imageView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback callback;
    android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_activity);

        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        surfaceHolder=surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
cameraImage();
            }
        });
        callback = new android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outputStream=null;
                File file_image = getDirc();

                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmms");
                String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
                String photo_file="PI_"+date+".jpg";
                String file_name = file_image.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+photo_file;
                File picfile=new File(file_name);

                try {

                    outputStream=new FileOutputStream(picfile);
                    outputStream.write(bytes);
                    outputStream.close();


                }catch (FileNotFoundException e){}
                catch (IOException ex){}
                finally {

                }
                refreshCamera();
                refreshGallery(picfile);

                try {
                    camera.stopPreview();
                }catch (Exception e){}

                try{

                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                    camera.startPreview();
                }catch (Exception e){}


            }


        };
    }
    private void refreshGallery(File file){
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));



    }

    public void refreshCamera(){

        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null){

            return;

        }

    }

    private File getDirc(){

File dics = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        return new File(dics ,"Camera");

    }

    public void cameraImage(){

        camera.takePicture(null , null ,callback);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

        try{

            camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();

        }catch (RuntimeException ex){



        }

        android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
        parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(30);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(353 , 288);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        try {

            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();


        }catch (Exception e){



        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        refreshCamera();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera=null;

    }
}
```

**camera_activity.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rel">

        <SurfaceView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/s">

        </SurfaceView>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/rel2"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/images"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:src="@drawable/menu"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:id="@+id/takeaphoto"
                android:src="@drawable/button"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/images"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/rel1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/switchcamera"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Well what is the problem? `camera==null`. Or not initialized.  Check before use. Or initialise. You did not assign it a pointer value.

Comment: @greenapps Could you show how to initialize it? If it's not.

Comment: `try{

            camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();

        }catch (RuntimeException ex){



        }`. You are trying to initialise it. But there will be a catch. And you do nothing in the catch so you know nothing. Instead you should inform the user and not continue with your code but return.